# Do all transactions show in metamask wallet?

Tags: metamask, etherscan, error

Bare with me I'm new here :) I've been selling art on Rarible but I can't tell if the Eth is going into my account. Because I'm minting nft's I can't keep track of my Eth total. My wallet activity doesn't say received when I sell something so that's where I'm getting confused. My Metamask extension always has errors on the manage extensions page and if I hover the cursor over the eth total on my wallet it always says "Balance may be outdated". Should incoming and outgoing activity show up on my wallet? Is Etherscan the log for Metamask or can a transaction show successful on Etherscan and get blocked because of a Metamask error?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately internal transactions are not displayed by Metamask. See this report https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/565.

Due to the decentralized nature of blockchain you should check multiple sources to be sure the balance is correct. Most of the time they will match and be correct but there is no guarantee.

Etherscan is a separate project from Metamask it shows more detailed information like blocks, transactions, accounts, etc. It is usually very used in the community.